# ConcurrentHashMap.containesKey for different instances of the class, but equal based on equal method

Tags: concurrenthashmap

Got a little bit confused using ConcurrentHashMap.

So, I'm storing my own class instances as key in it.
Let's call it Job.
Here it is.

```
public class Job {

private long id;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Job))
        return false;
    Job job = (Job)o;
    return job.getId() == getId();
}

}
```

Here is what I'm trying to do with it:

```
Job jobToAdd = new Job();
jobToAdd.setId(1);

Job jobToRemove = new Job();
jobToRemove.setId(1);

ConcurrentMap<Job, Long> jobsQueue 
    = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

jobsQueue.put(jobToAdd, jobToAdd.getId());

jobsQueue.containsKey(jobToRemove); //Returns FALSE
```

At some point I want to remove a job from this queue. I'm using different instance of the job class, but it has the same ID. I assume that *remove* is searching for keys based on *equals*, isn't it? Well, *containsKey*, for sure, but even *containsKey* returns FALSE. However,

```
jobsQueue.keySet().iterator().next().equals(jobToRemove);
```

returns TRUE.

Am I missing something here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Andrey

Answer (score 0):

Pardon my stupidity... I totally forgot to override hash function.